Horror Film - Driver breaks down and family disappears
I'm trying to identify a horror film that has the following plot:  
A man is driving with his family on a deserted road. His car breaks down. His wife and daughter disappear. He goes looking for them. He finds a sort of cabin. There is an old man and a woman there. 
All sorts of spooky things start to happen, until eventually the film climaxes revealing that it was all a guilt driven bad trip (drug trip)! The film reveals that he was supposed to deliver a drug cargo and didn't meet the deadline, so the drug dealers murdered his family. In a crisis of guilt, he tries to die by overdose because he had caused his family's death. 
I've tried looking everywhere for this and no success. I think if you don't already know it you won't be able to help, because it's been so hard to find it. 
I can tell you that:  The film has an IMDB page, because I checked after seeing it.  It's a film released between 2000 and 2012.  It's not something completely obscure, or trashy. But it seems impossible to find.  

This sounds a bit like 2005 movie Reeker (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reeker).

Not that one, unfortunately! Thanks.

Hello, is that The Hills Have Eyes ? Where takes the place when driver wake up?

@deadfish It's not, I'm afraid! The place where the driver wakes up it's the same shack or cabin that he finds when he goes looking for his family.

Sounds like Zabludivshiysya (2009)

The main character, his wife and small son lose their way and become stuck on a country road. As a result, they have to spend the night in their car. The following morning, the main character awakens alone, his wife and son having mysteriously disappeared. His preliminary searches bring the hero to a small lonely house, in which an old man and a young woman live. It seems that these strange tenants know about him and his family but try to hide their knowledge. For what reason?





Found it! I don't know how you did it, but you did it. Thou art a scholar.
